# sharepoint, powershell:compare csv to list and adding missing entries in the list

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, compare

**I need to compare сsv with the list and add missing items to the list. Add only from csv to the list.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. But in SharePoint list doesnt have any Unique column other than ID. Your CSV might not have that ID. So you should have an Unique calue column in both CSV and SP list. Get all the rows in CSV and SharePoint List in DataTable and compare both DataTable to obtain the distinct Values and upload those rows in SP List.

Comment: I do not know how to compare csv to the list. I get to compare and get missing elements in both lists .... but i need to compare it with the list. I can get a value from a condition "$_['Code'] -ne $row.code -and $_['code2'] -ne $row.code2"

Answer (score 0):

I believe Data in your CSV is in same order as it is in list ie first row of your CSV will be compared to first data from list shorted on ID in Descending order.

In CSV header names should be same as list columns.

Import CSV and iterate through each row,also get listItems separately and compare columns, something like this:

```
 $SPWeb = Get-SPWeb http://mysharepoint.org
 $SPList = $SPWeb.Lists["My List"]

 $listItems = $SPList.GetItems()

 ##Import your CSV
 $csv = Import-Csv "D:\Test.csv"
 $counter=0

 foreach ($item in $csv)          
 {

     if( $listItems[$counter]["Column"] -ne $item.Column)
     {
       #Fetch that item by ID and Update
       $SPListItem = $SPList.GetItemByUniqueId($listItems[$counter]['ID'])
       $SPListItem["Column"] = $item.Column
       $SPListItem.Update()
       $counter=$counter+1

     }

}
```

I have done it for one column, it can be done for n number of columns.

This is my first answer, please let me know if it worked :)

Comment: this does not work. I need to add items that are not in the list, but there are csv. Unique elements I define: $list.items|where-object {$_['code'] -eq $row.code}. The list contains many elements.